# Can I add a required passcode to my HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, passwords

I want to put an HTML form on my website for people to send in their RSVP to a party invite. I want to require them to put in a passcode (that will be printed on their invite) before they can submit the form. Is there a way to set a field requirement to an exact match of a pre-specified pin # or password using purely HTML (and JavaScript if necessary)?

For sake of an example, let's simply say I want the person's name and a yes or no for their RSVP.

```
<form>
    Name:
        <input type="text" name="name">
    RSVP:
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="yes">Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="no" checked>No<br>
    Secret Word:
        <input type="password" name="secretWord">
</form>
```

Comment: You can implement that field with HTML and check "the structure" with javascript, **BUT** if all passcodes are the same these 2 language are enough otherwise i recommend using PHP

Comment: You need to implement a validation in javascript also you need to store the passwords hashs to verify. you can see [more about here](https://medium.com/of-all-things-tech-progress/starting-with-authentication-a-tutorial-with-node-js-and-mongodb-25d524ca0359)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would have to use Javascript, so you would want

```
function check(){
    var pass = document.getElementById("pass_box").value;
    if(pass == "Y o u r p a s s w o r d"){
        // Do stuff
    }else{
        // Dont do stuff
    }
}
```

and your html code would look like this:

```
<form>
Name:
    <input type="text" name="name">
RSVP:
    <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rsvp" value="no" checked>No<br>
Secret Word:
    <input type="password" id="pass_box" name="secretWord">
<button onclick="check()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But this isnt very secure, because someone could just look at your code and see the password, but if its just for a party, it should be fine!
Anyway, there is your code! Hope this helps!

Comment: And my friend you think how long takes for me to find out what is the password? Are you passed "Information Security Principles" in university?

Comment: I understand that it's not secure (as does Robert, I assume since he said that in his answer). It's just a deterrent. By hacking the code, they wouldn't be gaining access to an info so I'm not worried about it. If it were something any more serious than party invites, I'd add extra security measures.

Comment: You could MD5 the password for some bit of security

Comment: I mean, I would use a hash, but to each his own